# Centering text in a div, div doesn't display in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fvkLfs09/
I would like to make this text on the right with numbers to be always centered in that blue div if that's possible.

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="season">
            <div class="triangle">
                <p class="seasonBanner">SEASON 1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="patch_table">   <a class="patchlink" href="#">
                                    <div class="patch_big">3.41</div>
                                  </a>

                <div class="patch_small">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="patch_table">   <a class="patchlink" href="'.$patch.'">
                                    <div class="patch_big">1.0.0.143</div>
                                  </a>

                <div class="patch_small">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
            </div>
</body>
```

and CSS

```
.seasonBanner {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -35px;
    left: -60px;
    position: relative;
    width: 113px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: white;
}
.triangle {
    width: 50%;
    height: 0;
    padding-left:50%;
    padding-top: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.triangle:after {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    margin-left:-500px;
    margin-top:-380px;
    border-left: 500px solid transparent;
    border-right: 500px solid transparent;
    border-top:464px solid rgb(102, 153, 255);
}
.seasonBanner:not(:first-of-type) {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.patchlink {
    color: white;
    font-size: 80%;
    width: 28px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(102, 153, 255, 0.7);
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
.patchlink:hover {
    background-color: rgb(102, 153, 255);
}
.patch_small {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
}
.patch_big {
    position: absolute;
    width: 15px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -8px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100%, 0);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100%, 0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.patch_table {
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
}
```

For some reason those links on the left do not show up on safari at all.

Here is a picture of how it would look like on safari: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyijC.png

Those blue divs should be on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example how to rotate and center text relative to another element...

```js
$(".text").css({'top':$(".box").height()+'px'});

var yoffset = ($(".box").height()-$(".text").width())/2;
var xoffset = ($(".box").width()-$(".text").height())/2;

$(".text").css({
    'top':$(".box").height()-yoffset+'px',
    'left':xoffset+'px'
});
```

```css
.box {
    position: relative;
    background: cyan;
    width: 1.5em;
    height: 100px;
}

.text {
    background: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}    
.rotate {
    /* Safari */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Firefox */
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* IE */
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Opera */
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Internet Explorer */
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
  
    -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%; /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
    <div class="text rotate">100.11</div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a chance to make it slimmer? like in my example it it should be as wide as your yellow box, and this link is really crucial to the website so I'm not really sure is jquery is the way to go

Comment: It can be any size you want. The javascript detects the size of the box and centers accordingly. It can all be done in pure javascript but easier to use jquery. I've changed the size of the container box to match closer to the height of text. Obviously you can change it to your needs with css withought affecting the javascript

Comment: I've tried your code (without the jquery for now) works fine on chrome but on safari it still http://i.imgur.com/Sku31bI.png doesnt want to show properly

Comment: I'll check safari later. Finished work now and it's the weekend ^^

Comment: When you say you tried my code without jQuery, did you modify the code at all? As it was written for jQuery, you can't use it as is and would obviously need to modify it to run in pure javascript mode. Without seeing the code on the page I can't really help.